# Is there a way to use raw_input (or equivalent) in a kivy application without interrupting the main loop?

Tags: python, loops, input, kivy, barcode

I know any loop in kivy interrupts the main loop and causes problems. I'm writing and application which needs to wait for input on the console sent via a barcode scanner which sends the code as a string on the terminal once it is scanned, the problem is if I use raw_input then the main kivy loop is interrupted, so is there a way to do this without conflicting the kivy application? Any help is highly appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried `sys.stdin.read()`? It does not block but might also return nothing.

Comment: Also I'm trying to use the code provided (by the scanner) to update a label, I have no problem doing this but I need to get the code to update the label, I don't know how to do this without using raw_input or sys.stdin.readline(). Also the code is printed in a TextInput text if it is focused when scanned, if that helps.

Comment: Yes, I initially used sys.std.readline() but the app stopped if there was no scanning, as opposed to returning nothing as you suggest.

Comment: If I use sys.stdin.read() or readline() the app doesn't even work. if I use raw_input the app freezes while waiting for input and doesn't even read the input. I guess because of what I said first about the kivy main loop which is clear in the Kivy doc.

Comment: @KlausD. Is there a way to make sys.stdin.read() work as you suggest i.e. just using the value when a product is scanned? I tried using if sys.stdin.read != None: , if sys.stdin.read() != "": and similar but didn't work. Don't know if that evaluation is accurate either. Also thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I once encountered a similar scenario (Waiting for input from RFID reader).
My final solution was to wait for the input in another daemon thread and populate any possible input to a `Queue()` and then reading from that `Queue()` in regular intervals using Kivy clock . Here is a sample code.

```
from queue import Queue, Empty

temp_queue = Queue()
READ_CARD_SLEEP_TIMEOUT = 5  # Seconds
EVENT_INTERVAL_RATE = 5
QUEUE_TIMEOUT = 1

def wait_for_blocking_io():
    while True:
        # Check whether input exists
        data = handler.fetch_data()
        if data:
            temp_queue.put(data)
        time.sleep(READ_CARD_SLEEP_TIMEOUT)

io_wait_thread = Thread(name='io_wait', target=wait_for_blocking_io, daemon=True)
io_wait_thread.start()
```

Then in your main app ask the kivy `Clock()` to check for possible data in `temp_queue`. Example code:

```
class MainScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__()
        self.event = Clock.schedule_interval(self.listen_for_data, EVENT_INTERVAL_RATE)

    # noinspection PyUnusedLocal
    def listen_for_data(self, dt):
        try:
            data = temp_queue.get(timeout=QUEUE_TIMEOUT)
            # Do whatever you want with data
        except Empty:
            pass
```

Comment: Hello @Juggernaut thanks for the help. I have a question, where does the carts variable come from? Also, I have noticed that the input (product code) from the scanned barcode goes to whatever application is in focus at the moment i.e. to terminal if im on the terminal, to text editor if im in text editor, and to any text input (ex. a ivy text input, the stack overflow comment box, etc) if it is focused, BUT if there is no text input FOCUSED nothing happens, would I have to use a text input focused to get the code or will the input listening work even if there is no text input field focused?

Comment: @AmonTzar I fixed the `carts` name. It was due to copying from the project I mentioned. Sorry. But why do you want it to write the input to the focused input? I mean why did you program it like this at the firsthand?

Comment: The TextInput was an idea as using raw_input and read() is being problematic, but initially I wanted (and I would prefer) to use the input as a variable to use it, I ultimately just want to show the scanned code into a kivy label, of course then when my app is more advanced use it for database operations etc... What I'm having trouble with is making the app just use any code scanned at any time without any problem.

Comment: I'm testing your code and will implement it into the app, I just got a meeting right now and will continue afterwards and update the results. Thank you a lot. One last question, will the scanned code be feed into the 'data' variable? as I have tried so far (I tried printing the data variable) it seems to not be getting the scanned code, or maybe I'm not understanding perfectly the code. Again, thanks a lot. I feel I'm getting closer to the solution.